# Getting the wrong timezone when outputting user registration date in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to output user registration time in the local timezone, but Wordpress stores the `user_registered`value in UTC format. Backend settings are set to be +2h.

The following code:

```
$user_registered = $user_info->user_registered;
```

will display the UTC time like `2018-10-25 15:04:45`, where I need it to be `2018-10-25 17:04:45`

I tried to get the local time of user registration with `get_gmt_from_date` function like this

```
$formatted_time = get_gmt_from_date( $user_registered, $format = 'H:i:s');
```

but that is not working. How do I output local time format for user registration time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's good. You want everything stored in UTC.

Just create a DateTime object, then set the appropriate time zone. As an example:

```
<?php

$x = new DateTime('2018-10-25 15:04:45', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $x->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
$x->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
echo $x->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
```

Which will output:

```
2018-10-25 15:04:45 
2018-10-25 17:04:45
```

See it here: https://3v4l.org/OF8Ff